# Check if Azure Service Bus topic is full

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Is there any way to (programmatically) find out, using `TopicClient` class, if an Azure Service Bus Topic is full **before** sending message to it?

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch a `Topic` using `TopicClient`, you get the information about it in an object of type [`TopicDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicdescription?view=azure-dotnet). `TopicDescription` has two properties: [`MaxSizeInMegabytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicdescription.maxsizeinmegabytes?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_TopicDescription_MaxSizeInMegabytes) (which gives you the maximum quota for the topic) and [`SizeInBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.topicdescription.sizeinbytes?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_TopicDescription_SizeInBytes) (which gives you current size of the topic). Using these two, you can determine if or not the Topic is full.

Comment: Caution note: I would be reluctant to do that before each Send operation, since it will probably hit the performance

Comment: Anything to do with entities management or state is a performance hit :) To add to that, I would ask why do you need to test this? Perhaps you have a topic of a wrong size? Or you have subscribers that are offline for two long and their messages are piling up? What I'm after is that a publisher should not be concerned about size of the topic for every publish.